# Wordpress, custom post type and posts query help!

Tags: posts, query

I have a homepage witch i am trying to query a custom post type as well as everything from the default posts,

right now i have 2 loops running everything looks good except i want the 2 different types to intermingle , if that makes sense.

Im running a jquery function that shows and hides posts from a either the custom post type or the default "Blog" post type. but since I have to loops the default posts always show up on top and the posts from the custom post type show up on the bottom, here is a link the my live page

http://themes.thefragilemachine.com/themachine_v4/

you can see that my custom post type is showing with a "w" icon, they are showing up near the end, but i want them to intermingle,. i know this is alot of type just trying to figure out the best way to explain what i would like too achieve. any help would be amazing! here is my code

```
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=6');?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="postitem mall floatleft myblog storm_fader">
            <div class="postitem-img lordfade">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('type2'); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="postitem-contentwrap">
            <div class="postitem-txt">
            <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
            <?php the_excerpt(''); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="postitem-info">
            <ul>
            <li><span class="post-label-blog"></span></li>
            <li class="spec"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <img src="/themachine_v4/wp-content/themes/themachine_v5_2/lib/imgs/img_gopost.jpg">
            </a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="postitem-shadow"></div>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h2 class="center" style="color:#FFF;">ERROR</h2>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>


            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php query_posts('post_type=work&posts_per_page=6');?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="postitem mall floatleft mywork storm_fader">
            <div class="postitem-img lordfade">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('type2'); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="postitem-contentwrap">
            <div class="postitem-txt">
            <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
            <?php the_excerpt(''); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="postitem-info">
            <ul>
            <li><span class="post-label-work"></span></li>
            <li class="spec"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <img src="/themachine_v4/wp-content/themes/themachine_v5_2/lib/imgs/img_gopost.jpg">
            </a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="postitem-shadow"></div>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h2 class="center" style="color:#FFF;">ERROR</h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing so many things wrong there, for example, you should only use `query_posts` once in a template file and on the main query of the page, anything else should be done using `get_posts` or `WP_Query`.

So to make you post types mingle you only need on query and you set the post type with an array:

```
<?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 6, 'post_type' => array('work','post')));
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="postitem mall floatleft myblog storm_fader">
        <div class="postitem-img lordfade">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('type2'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="postitem-contentwrap">
        <div class="postitem-txt">
        <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>
        <?php the_excerpt(''); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="postitem-info">
        <ul>
        <li><span class="<?php 
        if ($post->post_type =="post"){
            echo 'post-label-blog';
        }else{
            echo 'post-label-work';
        }?>"></span></li>
        <li class="spec"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <img src="/themachine_v4/wp-content/themes/themachine_v5_2/lib/imgs/img_gopost.jpg">
        </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postitem-shadow"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; 
else : ?>
    <h2 class="center" style="color:#FFF;">ERROR</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, this is alot cleaner although  im getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'  on line 16,

Comment: Yea sorry just updated the code, try now.

Comment: Amazing that works! just had 1 more question, if you notice the code. there is a span class called "post-label-blog", i created one for work/portfolio as well that is called "post-label-work" is there a way tell WP to replace "post-label-blog" with "post-label-work" depending on if im posting to that post type or not? thank you so much for your help i will mark this answered,

Comment: @The Fragile Machine : Yes you can ,you check the post type, i just updated my answer so try the new code.

Comment: That worked great! thank you so much! this is worth more than gold to me! :)